# Issues when trying to mock Apache HTTP Client with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am a beginner ramping up on Mockito. I have an HTTP get call which I would like to mock.

The Utility file which has to be tested is this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GoogleAccessor {
private HttpClient client ;

    public void getGoogle() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";
         client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my jUnit test

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class TestTest {

    @Mock
    private HttpClient mClient;

    @InjectMocks
    private GoogleAccessor dummy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddCustomer_returnsNewCustomer() throws Exception {
        when(mClient.execute(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(buildResponse(201, "OK", "{\"message\":\"Model was stored\"}"));
        dummy.getGoogle();
    }

    BasicHttpResponse buildResponse(int statusCode, String reason, String body) {
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(
                new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 0), statusCode, reason));
        if (body != null) {
            response.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(body.getBytes()));
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

As, mclient isnt initiated, I keep getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazon.cartographertests.accessors.TestTest.testAddCustomer_returnsNewCustomer(TestTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ...
```

UPDATE1: I have incorporated comments from @glytching & removed the variable initialization in setup()
I have incorporated comments from @Maciej Kowalski and made the client a class variable in Utility class

UPDATE 2:

The NPE error has been resolved after resolving to the right import -> import org.mockito.Mock;

But, the issue of not seeing mocked response still exists

Comment: `@InjectMocks` is pure magic evil. Pass the dependencies with the good old constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `mClient` as a mock here:

```
@Mock
private HttpClient mClient;
```

But you also assign it a concrete instance of `DefaultHttpClient` in `setUp()`:

```
mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Just remove that line from `setup()` and the instance of `mClient` in use in your test will be a mock.

**Update**: your updated question shows this import:

```
import org.easymock.Mock;
```

That should be

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
```

This instruction: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` wil initialise any class members annotated with `org.mockito.Mock`, it won't do anything to a class member annotated with `org.easymock.Mock` so I suspect that `mClient` is not being initialised and hence the NPE. When I run your code locally, with the correct import, the test completes successfully, no exceptions.

Note: there is also an issue inside `GoogleAccessor`, you instance the `HttpClient` explicitly inside `getGoogle` here ...

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

... so this method will never use the mocked `HttpClient`.

If you comment out this line:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

... and add this class member to `GoogleAccessor`:

```
private HttpClient client;
```

... then you'll find that your mocked client will be used inside `getGoogle()`.

For background; in order to use a mocked instance inside a class you must provide some way for the test runner to *inject* that mocked instance into the class. In your test case you are using `@InjectMocks` so you are instructing the test runner to inject your mock into `GoogleAccessor` but since there is no class member of that type the test runner has nothing to assign the mock *to*. In addition, even if it could assign the mock to something, you were declaring the http client **inside** `getGoogle()` thereby forcing all invocations of that method to use a concrete instance of `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: If i removed the initialization part . I am seeing an NPE ..Please see the updated question

Comment: @AdityaReddy I think you've imported the wrong `Mock`, I've updated the answer to address this point.

Comment: I have corrected it. That was foolish on my part..  But I still dont see the mocked response. I see the actual response being returned

Comment: I have updated the answer. With these changes in place I can confirm that the response returend by `getGoogle` is the expected response: `{"message":"Model was stored"}`.

Comment: Yupp, Thanks it works when I removed the initialization. So, can you please tell me whats the best practice in such cases. Should the initialization happen at class level. Something like this `private HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();` ??

Comment: Declare a constructor `public GoogleAccessor(HttpClient client)) { ... }` and supply the HttpClient instance at construction time, then you can invoke this from within your test passing in the mocked instance. If you cannot/will not deal with dependency injection then you could also declare a public no-args constructor which delegates to the other constructor like so: `this(new DefaultHttpClient());`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the client in the method itself. There is no way you can mock that unless you create a package level method:

```
HttpClient getNewClient(){
   return new DefaultHttpClient();
}
```

and use it instead in the method.

```
public void getGoogle() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";
    HttpClient client = getNewClient();
```

Then you would need to spy the class under test in order to keep the method under test as it is and mock the `getNewClient` method to return what you want:

```
@Mock
private HttpClient mClient;

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private GoogleAccessor dummy;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testAddCustomer_returnsNewCustomer() throws Exception {
    doReturn(null).when(mClient).execute(Mockito.any()));
    dummy.getGoogle();
}
```

you also need to use the `doReturn().when()` syntax instead of `when().then()` as you are dealing with a spy.

Comment: I have made the HttpClient a class variable. I am still seeing the issue. Regarding spy.. I did try with it and see the same issue. Is this working on your local?

Comment: you use mocking from `import org.easymock.Mock;`. Use org.mockito package

Comment: I have changed it and the NPE issue is resolved. Now the I see that the actual response is returned instead of mocked response

Comment: It worked on moving initialization also to class level. Thanks for looking into this.